# Visualforce Component on Dashboard Viewing As User

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

Is there a way to tell what user has been selected in the Viewing Dashboard as field? I want an embedded VF page that will automatically refresh based on that field.

Comment: checked the obvious ones (http headers and request parameters) to no avail :(

Answer (score 2):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_dashboard.htm

**RunningUserId**

```
SELECT Id, Description, DeveloperName, RunningUserId, RunningUser.isActive, Title, Type 
FROM Dashboard
```

I use `WHERE RunningUser.isActive = false OR Type = 'LoggedInUser'` so:

- I can see where we screwed up the deactivation of users and dashboard will fail to run (pain especially if it was scheduled)
- I look for candidate for delete/demotion when we've run out of the 5 dynamic dashboards limit.

Comment: But what if the dashboard allows you to change the running user?

Comment: Couldn't figure anything out either. I guess you'll have to add user lookup to your VF page and do the security-related stuff yourself, forget about leveraging `with sharing` magic...

Comment: Hello, so what would be the answer for this question?